# what exactly does fsck do under the covers (for UFS)?

Tags: filesystems, freebsd

If a computer crashes then the filesystem is an inconsistent state. What exactly is [fsck(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fsck&sektion=8) doing to restore to a usable filesystem?  Is there a backup table? Is it cross-checking metadata?

According to the man page it is able to fix:

> ```
>  Unreferenced inodes
>  Link counts in inodes too large
>  Missing blocks in the free map
>  Blocks in the free map also in files
>  Counts in the super-block wrong
> ```

but how can this happen?

Comment: http://lwn.net/Articles/248180/

Answer (score 1):

Unix stores file **metadata** in data files called directories,and it contains filename, owner,creation date etc.

And Unix file system uses a basic storage called **inodes**.Note that creating a new file actually changing the state of an inodes from free to allocated, writing metadata to a directory file，and writing data to the new file.

while file system corrupted，fsck check consists of reading all the inodes and attempting to resolve as many corruption issues as possible.